# Button to calculate route using user position in my webpage using Google Maps JS API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Basically what I'm trying to do is a Modal map which when opens shows the map but also has a button which can calculate the route using the browsing geolocation technology. The map is being showed at the modal but I cannot get my button to work and ask for geolocation and also to display a route.
This is the modal.

```
<a id="launchMap">Open Modal</a>


<!--  Modal Map -->
<div id="mapModal" class="modal-map">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content-map">
    <div class="modal-map-header">
        <span class="close-map">&times;</span>
        <h2>Ubicación</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="" id="direction-realestate">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-map-footer">
        <button onclick="setDirection()" class="btn" type="button"><span>Obtener Dirección</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script, the initMap() function is working properly

```
<!-- Map Function -->
<script>
function initMap() {
    var initLocation = {lat: 9.933632, lng: -84.1905311};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('direction-realestate'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: initLocation,
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: initLocation,
        map: map
    });
}

function setDirection() {


    if (navigator.geolocation) { //Checks if browser supports geolocation
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {                                                              //This gets the
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                    //users current
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                 //location
            var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); //Creates variable for map coordinates
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var mapOptions = //Sets map options
                {
                    zoom: 15,  //Sets zoom level (0-21)
                    center: coords, //zoom in on users location
                    mapTypeControl: true, //allows you to select map type eg. map or satellite
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL //sets map controls size eg. zoom
                    },
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //sets type of map Options:ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, TERRIAN
                };
            map = new google.maps.Map(/*creates Map variable*/ document.getElementById("direction-realestate"), mapOptions /*Creates a new map using the passed optional parameters in the mapOptions parameter.*/);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('direction-realestate'));
            var request = {
                origin: coords,
                destination: '9.933632,-84.1905311',
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}


// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('mapModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("launchMap");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-map")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    initMap();
    setDirection();
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I know I'm creating two maps variables but at the end the geolocation prompt is not working in any of my browsers, only in Firefox, any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your code from an HTTPS location?

Chrome gives this error from HTTP:

```
VM3859:20 [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See
```

And in IE:

If that is not the issue call the function with an error call back to see what the error is:

Note: Due to security restrictions, you need to run this on JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/psfw0004/

```js
function locateSuccess(pos) {
    console.log(pos);
    $('#result').text("success: " + pos.coords.latitude +':' +pos.coords.longitude);
}

function locateError(err) {
  console.log(err.code + ": " + err.message);
  $('#result').text(err.code + ": " + err.message);
}
var opts = {
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locateSuccess, locateError, opts);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locateSuccess, locateError, opts);" value="Get"/>
```